# how to handle filename having double dollar

Tags: bash, shell

I am just unable to search this in question list. Please help me here to find if someone already asked.

I am doing ssh on various m/c with filename like "/a/b/file$$$$".
    `ssh $host "/a/b/file$$$$"`

is now been replaced with 
    `ssh $host "/a/b/file54645464"`
above is the proc id of the bash scrpt which i am running.

so the issue is that later queries couldn't find this

any pointer will be of great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
ssh $host '/a/b/file$$$$'
```

Quoting with `'` instead of `"` prevents variable substitution.

From the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) (section `QUOTING`):

> Enclosing characters in single quotes preserves the literal value of each character within the quotes.

The variable substituted in your case is `$`:

> $
>
> Expands to the process ID of the shell. In a () subshell, it expands to the process ID of the current shell, not the subshell.

Since a `$` sign is (also) used to access the value of the `$` variable every pair (`$$`) is substituted with the process ID and that is why you end up with twice the process id.

Comment: Thanks this was useful. I replace my string like '/a/b/file/\$\$\$\$' and this worked well. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

use single quotes to have `$` not expanded:

```
$> echo '$ok'
$ok
```

Comment: Thanks this was useful. I replace my string like '/a/b/file/\$\$\$\$' and this worked well. Thanks again.